# how can i query firestore according to substring of document id?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

i have documents in following format

uid_112
uid_232
uid_433
mid_232
kid_221

i want to retrieve all the doc with doc id starting from uid

like uid*

ann will get the results as following documents

firestore.instance.collection("col").where(doc_val , "isMasterString" ,"uid" )

Answer (score 2):

I believe that is not possible in firestore. Perhaps you should change your implementation. Firstm I recommened using firestore auto ids in your document ids and store the uid list in array field of your document.

Refer to this structure

```
someCollection
    ATPawqV3XXehZn4W38fPPTXJ8 (document auto id)
         userIds (array field)
             0: uid_112
             1: uid_113
```

Then in your query, you can do this.

```
//in kotlin
someCollection.whereArrayContains("userIds", "uid_112")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no true wildcard queries for document ID in Firestore.  In fact, it's not a very good idea to put data in document IDs.  Queryable data should go in fields of documents.

What you should do in a field in your documents that help you make the queries you need.  If you have three different types of documents, "uid", "kid", "mid", perhaps you should use that string as the value of a field in the document.  If the field was called "type":

```
firestore
    .collection("col")
    .where("type" "==", "uid")
```