# How do I delete all Firestore documents for a specific user, based on a substring of the document ID?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I delete all Firestore documents for a specific user?
The Document IDs all begin with the user ID but include further unique identifiers after that (which is why I'm using a substring).
Below is the code:

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        setState(() {
          final userIdForDelete = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
          final userDocsForDelete = FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('user_docs')
              .doc(userIdForDelete?.substring(0, 28));
          if (userDocsForDelete != null) {
            userDocsForDelete.delete().then(
                  (doc) => debugPrint(
                  "User Documents Deleted"),
              onError: (e) => debugPrint(
                  "User Documents NOT Deleted $e"),
            );
          }
        });
      },
      child: const Text('Delete My Docs'),
    );
```

Comment: EZ way: call the `set()` method on that collection w empty arguments.

Comment: Could you please give an example of how the code should look? I'm new to development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I landed up adding a field in the document with the uid and used the batch delete method. This code seems to works.

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    setState(() async {

      final userIdForDelete = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;

      WriteBatch batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('user_document')
          .where('00_UID', isEqualTo: userIdForDelete)
          .get()
          .then((querySnapshot)=>{
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
          batch.delete(document.reference);
        })
      });
      batch.commit().then((document) {
        debugPrint('User Documents Deleted');
      });
      
    });
  },
  child: const Text('Delete User Data'),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the document IDs all **start** with the value you want to select on, you can use a condition on the name like this:

```
var prefix = userIdForDelete?.substring(0, 28);

final userDocsForDelete = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('user_docs')
    .where(FieldPath.documentId, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: prefix)
    .where(FieldPath.documentId, isLessThan: prefix + "~");
```

This only works for so-called prefix searches though, not for searches IDs that *contain* or *end with* a specific value. If you need those, consider storing the value you want to search for as a field in the document, so that you can put the condition on that field.

Also see:

- [how can i query firestore according to substring of document id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61981825/how-can-i-query-firestore-according-to-substring-of-document-id)
- [Firestore get document that contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579085/firestore-get-document-that-contains-a-string)
- [Google Firestore: Query on substring of a property value (text search)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568142/google-firestore-query-on-substring-of-a-property-value-text-search)